# Table data empty in athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, apache-iceberg

Hi I am struggling to create an table on aws athena, the table DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE iceberg.matrix_b_blueprint_1 (
 entrytime timestamp,
 key string,
 ingestion_time timestamp,
 field_0 int,
 field_1 string,
 field_2 boolean,
 field_3 int,
 field_4 string,
 field_5 string,
 field_6 string,
 field_7 boolean,
 field_8 int,
 field_9 int,
 field_10 int,
 field_11 int,
 field_12 int,
 insert_time timestamp)
 PARTITIONED BY (month(`entrytime`))
 LOCATION 's3://
  foundry/datalake/blueprints/bp_blueprint_1/data/'
 TBLPROPERTIES (
  'table_type'='iceberg',
  'format'='parquet',
  'write_compression'='ZSTD'
    );
```

The data is sitting on this location:

```
s3://foundry/datalake/blueprints/bp_blueprint_1/data/entrytime_month=2022-06/
```

When I  crate the table it create it but it is empty, I tried MCK repair as well but didn't work. Any pointers?

Comment: Does MSCK Repair Table return something?

Comment: `PARTITIONED BY (month('entrytime'))` looks a little strange. Normally it would be `PARTITIONED BY (column_name data_type)`. Try changing it to: `PARTITIONED BY (entrytime_month date)`

Comment: MCSK is not supported at this stage, I get:

Query type not supported by Athena Iceberg at this time. @Robert

Comment: Could you check your partitioning syntax, as John pointed out? Also try PARTITIONED BY (month(entrytime)), without the quotes.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if write_compression is case sensitive, so try zstd instead of ZSTD

Comment: I've removed the partition and the compression but the tables are still empty.